# IBM Worklight - How can I display the content a URL refers to, without losing app context?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

When writing a Worklight app it is *verboten* to change the URL of the DOM in which the application is running. This makes sense as a hypertext move to another URL will obliterate the state of the app.

On occasion however, in my app I receive a URL for a news article and the user wishes to read it. Displaying the new content in an iFrame would start to address the requirement, but then I need navigation controls, etc. and it starts to feel like I am reinventing a wheel.

Does Worklight, or one of the mobile JS frameworks provide a "browser in browser" experience that I need here?

Comment: if my answer below helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worklight utilizes Cordova. Cordova makes it possible to display just what you wanted, a "browser in a browser" - [InAppBrowser](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser).

> The InAppBrowser is a web browser view that displays when calling
>   window.open(), or when opening a link formed as `<a target="_blank">`.

Try that.

No setup is required as the `InAppBrowser` plug-in is already part of the Worklight project (this may differ depending on your Worklight version; If you are using 6.x you're OK).

All you need to do is to call up the URL. For example, in `yourProject\apps\yourApp\common\main.js`:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
```

Once the app initializes it will open the InAppBrowser:

[image]

And once tapping the `Done` button, you're back in the app.
You can of course not specify the `location` attribute so the navigation bar won't display. In that case, in order to go back to the app the user will need to tap the `Back` button:

[image]